# How do I use sftp to get a directory and all its contents?

Tags: directory, scp, sftp

When I try to use the command `get` from sftp, I get the error saying that it is not a normal file.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think you're right... it is a duplicate... but the answer given by @uther is more thorough than the answer given before to the other question... Is there a way to post his answer onto the other question.  Since my question is so similarly, feel free to delete my question but please repost his answer on the other question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can connect to the host using `sftp -r` and then `get` the directory. If you forget to use `-r` when you connect, you can use `get -r`.

`sftp -r me@somehost`

Or

```
sftp> get -r tmp/
Fetching /home/me/tmp/ to tmp
Retrieving /home/me/tmp
/home/me/new.orig.dmp            100%  417KB 416.8KB/s   00:00    
/home/me/untangle.dmp        100%  398KB 398.3KB/s   00:00    
/home/me/repos.orig.dmp          100%  415KB 415.2KB/s   00:00    
/home/me/me-untangle.dmp 100%   32KB  32.4KB/s   00:00    
sftp>
```

If you want to always ensure you pass `-r` to `sftp`, add it as an alias to your `~/.bashrc` or similar.

`alias sftp="sftp -r"`

From `man 1 sftp`

```
 -r      Recursively copy entire directories when uploading and download‐
         ing.  Note that sftp does not follow symbolic links encountered
         in the tree traversal.
         .........

 get [-Ppr] remote-path [local-path]
         ........
         If either the -P or -p flag is specified, then full file permis‐
         sions and access times are copied too.
         If the -r flag is specified then directories will be copied
         recursively.  Note that sftp does not follow symbolic links when
         performing recursive transfers.
```

Comment: why does not my sftp client didn't has a -r option? 

>>>>>sftp: illegal option -- r

Comment: sftp: illegal option -- r on CentOS 6.4 openssh-clients-5.3p1-84.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: in my ubuntu OS , its working.